# Problems creating depth images in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, depth, depth-buffer

I want to create some depth images and convert the values to real world distances in meter.

So to get to the depth images I am using this example:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/877170/render-scene-depth-to-a-texture.html

however it is not working very well for me, since I dont get much different values.

At the moment moment the convertion is done like:

```
        double step = (_zFar - _zNear) / 255.0;
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
            {
                //compute real depth value in meters from the normalized z-buffer [0..1] values
                //z-buffer values are non-linear so have to apply transformation to linearize the distance in world-space coordinates
                float z = 2.0f * _zNear * _zFar /
                        (_zFar + _zNear - (2.0f * tex2d.GetPixel(h,w).a - 1.0f) * (_zFar - _zNear));

                z = (float) (z / step);
                Debug.Log(tex2d.GetPixel(h, w).a + " -> " + z);

                Color c = new Color(z, z, z, z);
                tex2d.SetPixel(h, w, c);
            }
        }
```

For zFear & zNear I take the nearClipPlane & farClipPlane values.

In the one pic you can see the Log output of the values and the other ne an example of the saved image.

[image: current image]

[image: current image values]

Comment: You *are* getting varied data out. Pull that image into GIMP and adjust the values with the curve tool. Yes, the left half is broken, probably too far away, unclear, but the right half? Lots of good data there. Your eye just can't tell.

Comment: OK and you think the Convention to real world values ist right too?

Comment: No idea. I'm not even sure how I'd come to the conclusion one way or the other.